# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 using fetch-mock-jest for /localRoute mock

Tags: jestjs, fetch-mock

So fetch-mock-jest is based on fetch-mock (***it's not jest-fetch-mock..***)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock-jest

http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/

**The problem I have is:**

```
// inside my test file
fetchMock.restore().mock('https://someSiteOnTheInternet.com', someResponse)

// inside my tested file
fetch('https://someSiteOnTheInternet.com').then(...)
```

**The above is working** but as soon as I try **a local route** it's **not working anymore**

```
// inside my test file
fetchMock.restore().mock('/myProxy', someResponse)

// inside my tested file
fetch('/myProxy').then(...)
```

This one ('/myProxy') will fail with the error :

```
console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
  Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you check if the port is already reserved ?

Comment: hmm yes localhost is not used ...

Comment: not localhost as a whole, I meant port `80`, as it could be used by a running process during making the test.

Comment: no I ran lsof -nP -iTCP:80 | grep LISTEN ; port 80 is not used

Answer (score 1):

you can set `DEBUG=fetch-mock*` before running your tests and that will give a lot of output to show what's going on in fetch-mock's internals.

Comment: Where exactly do I set this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a conflict with docker,
is your front dockerized?
do you have docker running for your back-end?
can you stop docker/restart your machine and try running only your front without docker?

Comment: I'm not using docker for front or back-end, docker ps -a does not return any running container.